# Fun probability baseball question throwing strikes and balls

Tags: probability

In a problem in the book, there is a batter never swings, and the pitcher has a .5 probability to strike and a .5 to throw a ball.

In this situation, we found:
P(batter strikes out) = 21/32
P(batter walks) = 11/32

(Keep in mind that it takes 3 strikes to strike out and 4 balls to walk)

We found this by adding the probability of the batter striking out on the 3rd, 4th, 5th, and 6th pitch.

To do this:

```
P(Strike out on 3rd pitch) = (.5)^3 = 4/32  (3 strikes)

P(Strike out on 4th pitch) = C(3, 2)(.5)^2(.5)(.5) = 6/32
```

(2 strikes, 1 ball, then another strike)

```
P(Strike out on 5th pitch) = C(4, 2)(.5)^2(.5)^2(.5) = 6/32
```

(2 strikes, 2 balls, then another strike)

```
P(Strike out on 6th pitch) = C(5, 2)(.5)^2(.5)^3(.5) = 5/32
```

(2 strikes, 3 balls, then another strike)

So, add those up to get `P(Strike out) = 21/32`

Find the probability for P(pitcher throws a strike) for which P(batter walks) = P(batter strikes out) = 1/2

My thinking was to turn this into an equation. Let x represent P(pitcher throws a strike). So then we have P(strike out) is

= `x^3 + C(3,2)x^3(1-x) + C(4,2)x^3(1-x)^2 + C(5,2)x^3(1-x)^3`

= `x^3( 1 + C(3,2)(1-x) + C(4,2)(1-x)^2 + C(5,2)(1-x)^3`

This makes it a little easy to try out... but to solve I was thinking that if we need 21/32 to be 1/2 then.... (21/32)x = .5 => x = 16/21. But I am not sure what to do with this

Comment: The equation you have is correct. The solution is approximately $0.421407$, and I don't think there is way to solve it by hand.

Comment: It is a bit simpler to imagine the pitcher always throws six pitches, then figure out whether the batter walks or strikes out.  When you write the equation, it appears $x$ is the probability of a strike and the total formula is the chance to strike out.  Are you looking to find the strike probability that gives a strikeout probability of $\frac 12$?

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes that is correct. I am Are you looking to find the strike probability that gives a strikeout probability of 1/2

Comment: Be honest, did you put the word "fun" in the title hoping to get more clicks?  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p = P(strike)$ then the following equation is what you presented:

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
P(out) &= p^3(1 + \binom{3}{1}(1-p) + \binom{4}{2}(1-p)^2 + \binom{5}{3}(1-p)^3)\\
&=p^3(1 + 3(1-p) + 6(1-p)^2 + 10(1-p)^3)\\
&=p^3(1 + 3-3p + 6(1-2p+p^2) + 10(1-3p+3p^2-p^3)  ) \\
&=p^3(-p^3+36p^2-45p+20 )\\
P(walk) &= (1-p)^4(1 + \binom{4}{1}p + \binom{5}{2}p^2)\\
&=(p^4-4 p^3+6 p^2-4 p+1)(1+4p + 10p^2)\\
&=10 p^6-36 p^5+45 p^4-20 p^3+1
\end{array}
$$

Either of which you can set equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ and throw at Wolfram to get real roots in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ denote the probability that the pitcher throws a strike. We are looking for $p$ such that
$$\text{P(strike out)} = p^3 + {3 \choose 2} p^3 (1-p) + {4 \choose 2} p^3 (1-p)^2 + {3 \choose 2} p^3 (1-p)^3 = 0.5$$
After expanding $(1-p)^2$ and $(1-p)^3$, and combining terms, you will come to a solution of the form:
$$a p^6 + b p^5 + c p^4 + d p^3 - 0.5 = 0$$
This sixth-order polynomial will have six roots, each of which is a solution to the equation.  However, since we are looking to find a probability, we are only interested in real roots on the interval $[0,1]$. Use whatever method you prefer for finding the roots of a polynomial (e.g. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-10%2ap%5E6%2B36%2ap%5E5-45%2ap%5E4%2B20%2ap%5E3-0.5%3D0)), and you will find that only one of the roots in this particular problem satisfies the criteria.  That is your answer.